# Connecting to SQL Express from WSL - SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sql-server-express, sqlclient

I've been working through this for nearly two days and I'm running out of options. Maybe you guys can help.

Background: I migrated a .netcore api from Windows to WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). My Database is running on Windows. When attempting to run `dotnet ef database update` it gives me the error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid: Connection string is not valid)
```

My Connection string (ip is placeholder):

```
"Server=192.168.0.1,1433/SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=no"
```

I've googled that error and tried (or have already done) many of the suggested solutions, including:

- ensured my inbound ports are setup for windows firewall; 1433 for Sql Server and 1434 for Sql Server Browser
- ensured that sql server and sql server browser are running
- ensured that TCP/IP is Enabled in SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
- Ensured that the IP Address for wsl is Active, Enabled, and has TCP port 1433 TCP/IP properties
- Ensured that TCP Port is set to 1433 for TCP/IP properties > IPAll
- I can successfully ping the ip
- I can successfully telnet the ip
- I've checked that the instance name is SQLEXPRESS
- Ensured that my database Allows remote connections
- Ensured that the database allows mixed sql server and windows authentication
- I've tried many variations of the connection string - with and without Encrypt, TrustServerCertificate, User Id, and Password (used sa)
- I've tried several variations of the Server: IP,Port, IP,Port/InstanceName, IP/InstanceName, InstanceName, localhost/InstanceName, MachineName/InstanceName, IP/InstanceName,Port
- I've tried prefixing the above with tcp:

On the windows side using powershell I ran the following:

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost,1433;Database=MyDatabase;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=True;User ID=sa;Password='';Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
$sqlConn
```

It prints out all of the correct information. Omitting the `Encrypt=no` will give me an error 40 which is related to a self-signed ssl cert. Omitting the User Id and Password still successfully connect.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you use this method to get the IP address of the host https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip ? Doesn't make sense to use both instance name and port number. If you have a fixed port just use that. `Integrated Security=true` won't work from WSL as it's not domain joined, but that is not your issue yet. Also when you use `Integrated Security=true` it makes no sense to supply a username/password.

Comment: The problem has now been solved. (I did get the IP that way) I think there were a few issues. 1. the 'sa' user wasn't enabled. *eyeroll*. I ended up creating a new login for this project specifically (which was how it was on the old machine). Once I removed the `Integrated Security=true` and the instance name it worked. In the end, I think the `Integrated Security` was the kicker. Thanks! If you want the internet points, feel free to write up an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: One more thing. I was able to troubleshoot this better using `sqlcmd` as it gave better error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the instance name if you are using a fixed port. You certainly shouldn't be specifying the port after the instance name.

And SQL Authentication uses `Integrated Security=False`. If it's `true` then it uses Windows Authentication and it makes no sense to pass a username and password. You can't use Windows Authentication from WSL.

```
Server=192.168.0.1,1433;Database=MyDatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=sa;Password=''
```

Add `TrustServerCertificate=True` if really necessary, be aware that it's a security risk.

Comment: The TrustServerCertificate is only used locally. Thanks Charlieface.